# Erro em npm run dev

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

Estou tentando executar o comando `npm run dev` em um projeto desenvolvido por outra pessoa.
Esse é a configuração no package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
```

E este é o erro:

```
node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:93
                throw err;
                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
```

O projeto é em Laravel e usa webpack. Já tentei remover os pacotes npm e reinstalá-los, limpei o cache, reinstalei o node, atualizei os pacotes, mas nada ajudou.
Como eu poderia corrigir?

Comment: acrescenta o codigo do app.js

Comment: não tenho esse arquivo no projeto.

Comment: Sem o código fica complicado poder ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Consegui corrigir, vou colocar a resposta aqui, talvez ajude alguém com o mesmo problema.

edite a linha:

```js
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix')
```

para isto:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix')
```